# Using Facebook Graph API to post on user wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Graph API to post from `user1` on `user2` wall.

I've got an `access_token` for `user1` with `publish_actions` permission, like It says in [the Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/user/feed#publish).
 and called

```sh
access_token='<token-for-user1>'
user2='<id-of-user2>'
curl -s \
    -XPOST \
    -d "access_token=$access_token" \
    -d "message=$message" \
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/${user2}/feed"
```

but all I get is:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '$user2' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "***********"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I thank you in advance,

Ido

---

Login script:

```sh
app_access_token="$app_id|$client_token"

# Give user_code to user1, and save code as $code
curl -s \
    -XPOST \
    -d "access_token=$app_access_token" \
    -d 'scope=publish_actions' \
    -d 'redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/device/login'

# user1 goes to https://www.facebook.com/device
...

# Save access_token in $access_token and use in the code above
curl -s \
    -XPOST \
    -d "access_token=$app_access_token" \
    -d "code=$code" \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/device/login_status'
```

Thing I've added to the app:

- Facebook Login

  - Valid OAuth redirect URIs = https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.htmlRemove
  - Login from Devices = Yes
- Settings

  - Native or desktop app? = Yes
  - Is App Secret embedded in the client? = Yes *when it is No it also does not work*

Comment: As of April 24,2018, the pubish_actions permission has been removed. 
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions#permissions-publish)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to post on the wall of another user. You can only post on the wall of the current user, with his own Access Token and the `publish_actions` permission.

Sharer.php offers the possibility to select a friend, that´s the only way: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[encoded-url]

You can also use the Share Dialog, it offers the option to select a friend too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: Is there any other way then?

Comment: i have included a way. it is NOT possible with the API, but with sharer.php or the share dialog.

Answer (score 2):

> As of April 24,2018, the `pubish_actions` permission has been removed.
> Please see the [Breaking Changes Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide
> a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage
> you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

See Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions#permissions-publish